# a problem with launching the MoveIt! Setup Assistant

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the instructions to [install the MoveIt!](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Installation). Now I meet an unknown error when launching the MoveIt! Setup Assistant with `roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch`.

```
REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-1] has died!</p>
process has died [pid 14447, exit code -11, cmd /home/handwerk/moveit/devel/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/handwerk/.ros/log/ba8fef58-5540-11e5-ab9d-ac72894ef665/moveit_setup_assistant-1.log].
log file: /home/handwerk/.ros/log/ba8fef58-5540-11e5-ab9d-ac72894ef665/moveit_setup_assistant-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo (installed from debians).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217186/a-problem-with-launching-the-moveit!-setup-assistant/) by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
but I meet a warning when installing dependencies with `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y`

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
```

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
I must install correctly the ROS by debian. where can be the problem ?

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
I install the Movelt! by the first choice. Actually I haven't followed the third step ( install the ros-hydro-moveit-full-pr2 )as I don't use it.

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
oh! I install the moveit! also by the second choice, now I have removed the moveit file and reinstalled the moveit! by the debian packge.but the error still happens

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
no SEGFAULT with the apt-get moveit.

what's the meaning of `rm -rf /path/to/catkin_ws/{build,devel}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

unexpectedly I launched normally the moveit! setup assistant with the help of gvdhoorn. The total process was as follows:

According to the answer in the http://answers.ros.org/question/193137/problems-with-moveit-exit-code-11/
I guess I had also a problem with my graphic driver.

1. I followed the http://askubuntu.com/questions/475972/error-couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig-ubuntu-12-04 to install the xserver-xorg.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

sudo reboot
```

but after rebooting I met the same error .And the touchpad also became invalid . then I tried to check the system Settings, but the settings crashed(could not be opened).

2. I  installed the ubuntu-desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

In this way the system Settings could be opened ,then I tried to launch the movit! and succeeded unexpectedly .
So I think the "Exit Code -11" is probably related to both the xserver-xorg and the ubuntu-desktop.

---

Originally posted by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) with karma: 51 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-08**:
Good to hear that you got it to work. One approach that I'd have suggested would be to run the setup assistant in GDB, so we could get a stacktrace. That would've likely showed some issue with OpenGL initialisation and / or interaction.

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-08**:
thanks, this approach is also worth trying,

**Comment by [carlos.atx](https://answers.ros.org/users/29794/carlos.atx/) on 2017-03-23**:
Hello, I tried this solution but am still getting the same error as you along with "process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [5132]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: error while loading shared libraries: libmoveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core.so.0.7.3: "

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which of the tutorials did you follow? The 'Ubuntu installation' or the 'Additional Source Installation Instructions'? Also: which OS is this, which version, which ROS release and how did you install ROS (from debians, or also from source)?

---

Edit:

The MoveIt tutorial you linked gives you a choice:

1. install MoveIt using apt-get ('ubuntu install): this is for 'normal' users
2. install MoveIt by compiling from sources using catkin_make ('source installation'): this is for developers.

Which of those two options did you do?

I'm asking all of this because if you don't get SEGFAULTs with the debians, and you don't want to develop MoveIt itself, we can save us a lot of trouble by just installing the debs (and not debug your from-source build).

---

Edit 2:

> I must install correctly the ROS by debian. where can be the problem ?

Please remove all `moveit_*` packages from your catkin workspace, do `rm -rf /path/to/catkin_ws/{build,devel}`, then run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full`.

Then try again.

---

Edit 3:

> I install the Movelt! by the first choice. Actually I haven't followed the third step ( install the ros-hydro-moveit-full-pr2 )as I don't use it.

`/home/handwerk/moveit/devel/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant`: this path is in the error msg you pasted in your question. That would seem to suggest you compiled moveit from sources.

Do you get the `exit code -11` (`SEGFAULT`) with the `apt-get` moveit as well?

---

Edit 4:

> oh! I install the moveit! also by the second choice, now I have removed the moveit file and reinstalled the moveit! by the debian packge.but the error still happens

> no SEGFAULT with the apt-get moveit.

Good.

> what's meaning of `rm -rf /path/to/catkin_ws/{build,devel}`?

It removes your previous 'from source' MoveIt build, to avoid you accidentally mixing those up with the MoveIt install from debs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
thanks for your attention, I follow your steps ,but the error still happens.

```
REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has died [pid 15519, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-07**:
You'll have to provide more information then: what are you trying to do exactly? Does the setup assistant crash immediately after launching it? Or only after you *load* a urdf or MoveIt pkg?

As a wild guess: do you have correct 3D drivers installed for your graphics card?

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
actually I have no explicit destination, and only try to install correctly

yes, immediately crach after launching. I remember I have installed the full ROS.I have already met the error before installing the moveit(though maybe no need for installing the moveit)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-07**:\

> As a wild guess: do you have correct 3D drivers installed for your graphics card?

can you run `rviz` normally?

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
l have not installed 3D drivers and run rviz.

**Comment by [Handwerker](https://answers.ros.org/users/23738/handwerker/) on 2015-09-07**:
rviz can launch correctly. I have not used the tool to do something.